# Grouping and summarizing data across a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr, lapply

So I have this dataframe in r, where the data is either like "up" or "down" for example,

```
df <- data.frame(Var1 = c("up", "down", "up", "down"),
                Var2 = c("down", "up", "down", "down"),
                Var3 = c("down", "down", "up", "up")
)
   df
```

What I want to do is use use group_by to make each column a group, then summarize to get the counts of the ups and down in each column.

I've come up with this so far,

```
newdf <- lapply(df[1:3], function(x){
     group_by(.[[x]])%>%
     summarize(n = n())
  })

newdf
```

but keep getting an error. It seems to not recognize the "."

```
Error in group_by(.[[x]]) : object '.' not found
```

Does anyone have any advice?

Also I'm using the tidyverse package, which I believe includes dyplyr

Comment: `.` doesn't mean anything in the context you are using it. you would want to use `df` instead here.

Comment: Using base R, how about trying `sapply(df, table)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here a way to create a table counting all variables

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Var1 = c("up", "down", "up", "down"),
                 Var2 = c("down", "up", "down", "down"),
                 Var3 = c("down", "down", "up", "up")
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  count(name,value) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,values_from = n,values_fill = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you! I haven't heard of pivot_longer or pivot_wider, previously, but this code worked much better.